# Nodes displayed at different distances with same commands

Tags: tikz-pgf

I want the nodes for `A`, `B`, `C`, and `D` of `rectangle ABCD` to be placed the same distance, `0.15cm` from the sides of a `quadrilateral PQRS`.  It is evident that they are not.  I put the nodes in circles, and I marked the points on these circles that are closest to the sides of the quadrilateral with a small green discs.  These green discs are not the same distance from the sides of the quadrilateral.  I also used used commands like

```
\draw[dashed] ($(A)!0.15!-90:(S)$) -- ($(S)!0.15!90:(A)$);
```

to mark line segments that should be `0.15cm` from the sides of the quadrilateral. It is evident that they are not.  Why is there inconsistency in `TikZ` rendering these commands?

```
\documentclass{amsart}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,positioning,intersections,quotes}


\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}

%Vertex A is located. It is a vertex on the bottom edge of the rectangle.
\coordinate (A) at (0,0);
\path[name path=a_path_to_define_the_bottom_side_of_rectangle] (0,0) -- (4,0);

%Vertex A is the midpoint of side PS of the circumscribing quadrilateral.
\coordinate (P) at (-2.25,0.75);
\coordinate (S) at (2.25,-0.75);
\path (P) -- (S);


%Vertex B of the rectangle is located. It is the intersection of a horizontal line
%through A and the line of slope 4/5 through S. Vertex R of the circumscribing
%quadrilateral is located so that B is the midpoint of side RS.
\path[name path=a_path_to_define_RS_of_quadrilateral] (S) -- ($(S) +({atan(4/5)}:2.5)$);
\coordinate[name intersections={of=a_path_to_define_the_bottom_side_of_rectangle and a_path_to_define_RS_of_quadrilateral, by=B}];
\draw let \p1=($(S)-(B)$), \n1={atan(\y1/\x1)} in coordinate (R) at ($(B) +(\n1:{veclen(\x1,\y1)})$);
\draw[green] (R) -- (S);

%Vertex Q of the circumscribing quadrilateral is located. Since vertex D
%of the inscribed rectangle is to be the midpoint of side PQ of the circumscribing
%quadrilateral, side AD is to be parallel to QS. So, Q is a point on the vertical
%line through S. Q is also twice the distance from P as D is from P.
\path[name path=a_path_to_locate_Q] (S) -- ($(S) +(0,3.5)$);
\path[name path=another_path_to_locate_Q] let \p1=($(P)-(0,0)$) in ($(P) +(0:{2*veclen(\x1,\y1)})$) arc (0:20:{2*veclen(\x1,\y1)});
\coordinate[name intersections={of=a_path_to_locate_Q and another_path_to_locate_Q, by=Q}];


%C is the midpoint of side QR of the circumscribing quadrilateral.
\draw[name path=side_QR] (Q) -- (R);
\path[name path=a_path_to_locate_C] (B) -- ($(B) +(0,2)$);
\coordinate[name intersections={of=side_QR and a_path_to_locate_C, by=C}];

%Vertex D of the rectangle is located.
\draw  let \p1=($(A)-(B)$) in coordinate (D) at ($(C) +({-1*veclen(\x1,\y1)},0)$);

%Rectangle ABCD is drawn.
\draw (A) -- (B) -- (C) -- (D) -- cycle;

%The labels for the vertices of the rectangle are typeset.
\draw let \p1=($(P)-(S)$), \n1={atan(\y1/\x1)} in  node[anchor={\n1+90}, inner sep=0,draw,circle] at ($(A)!0.15!-90:(S)$){$A$};
\draw let \p1=($(R)-(S)$), \n1={atan(\y1/\x1)} in  node[anchor={\n1+90}, inner sep=0,draw,circle] at ($(B)!0.15!-90:(R)$){$B$};
\draw let \p1=($(Q)-(R)$), \n1={atan(\y1/\x1)} in  node[anchor={\n1-90}, inner sep=0,draw,circle] at ($(C)!0.15!90:(R)$){$C$};
\draw let \p1=($(P)-(Q)$), \n1={atan(\y1/\x1)} in  node[anchor={\n1-90}, inner sep=0,draw,circle] at ($(D)!0.15!90:(Q)$){$D$};

\draw[fill=green] ($(A)!0.15!-90:(S)$) circle (1pt);
\draw[dashed] ($(A)!0.15!-90:(S)$) -- ($(S)!0.15!90:(A)$);

\draw[fill=green] ($(B)!0.15!-90:(R)$) circle (1pt);
\draw[dashed] ($(B)!0.15!-90:(R)$) -- ($(R)!0.15!90:(B)$);

\draw[fill=green] ($(C)!0.15!90:(R)$) circle (1pt);
\draw[dashed] ($(C)!0.15!90:(R)$) -- ($(R)!0.15!-90:(C)$);

\draw[fill=green] ($(D)!0.15!90:(Q)$) circle (1pt);
\draw[dashed] ($(D)!0.15!90:(Q)$) -- ($(Q)!0.15!-90:(D)$);


%Quadrilateral PQRS is drawn.
\draw (P) -- (Q) -- (R) -- (S) -- cycle;
\node[anchor=east, inner sep=0] at ($(P) +(-0.15,0)$){$P$};
\node[anchor=south, inner sep=0] at ($(Q) +(0,0.15)$){$Q$};
\node[anchor=west, inner sep=0] at ($(R) +(0.15,0)$){$R$};
\node[anchor=north, inner sep=0] at ($(S) +(0,-0.15)$){$S$};

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Don't you need to tell it you mean an absolute distance and not a proportion?

Comment: @cfr  Hmmm.  I forgot that with out units `TikZ` calculates the distance from the sides as a proportion of the length of the line segment with the specified endpoints.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you do not specify the units, then you are asking for the point which is, say, 15% of the way from the first point to the second. If you mean 1.5mm, then you must say `0.15cm` (or `1.5mm`) explicitly:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=10pt]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,intersections}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\coordinate (A) at (0,0);
\path[name path=a_path_to_define_the_bottom_side_of_rectangle] (0,0) -- (4,0);
\coordinate (P) at (-2.25,0.75);
\coordinate (S) at (2.25,-0.75);
\path (P) -- (S);
\path[name path=a_path_to_define_RS_of_quadrilateral] (S) -- ($(S) +({atan(4/5)}:2.5)$);
\coordinate[name intersections={of=a_path_to_define_the_bottom_side_of_rectangle and a_path_to_define_RS_of_quadrilateral, by=B}];
\draw let \p1=($(S)-(B)$), \n1={atan(\y1/\x1)} in coordinate (R) at ($(B) +(\n1:{veclen(\x1,\y1)})$);
\draw[green] (R) -- (S);
\path[name path=a_path_to_locate_Q] (S) -- ($(S) +(0,3.5)$);
\path[name path=another_path_to_locate_Q] let \p1=($(P)-(0,0)$) in ($(P) +(0:{2*veclen(\x1,\y1)})$) arc (0:20:{2*veclen(\x1,\y1)});
\coordinate[name intersections={of=a_path_to_locate_Q and another_path_to_locate_Q, by=Q}];
\draw[name path=side_QR] (Q) -- (R);
\path[name path=a_path_to_locate_C] (B) -- ($(B) +(0,2)$);
\coordinate[name intersections={of=side_QR and a_path_to_locate_C, by=C}];
\draw  let \p1=($(A)-(B)$) in coordinate (D) at ($(C) +({-1*veclen(\x1,\y1)},0)$);
\draw (A) -- (B) -- (C) -- (D) -- cycle;

\draw let \p1=($(P)-(S)$), \n1={atan(\y1/\x1)} in  node[anchor={\n1+90}, inner sep=0,draw,circle] at ($(A)!0.15!-90:(S)$){$A$};
\draw let \p1=($(R)-(S)$), \n1={atan(\y1/\x1)} in  node[anchor={\n1+90}, inner sep=0,draw,circle] at ($(B)!0.15!-90:(R)$){$B$};
\draw let \p1=($(Q)-(R)$), \n1={atan(\y1/\x1)} in  node[anchor={\n1-90}, inner sep=0,draw,circle] at ($(C)!0.15!90:(R)$){$C$};
\draw let \p1=($(P)-(Q)$), \n1={atan(\y1/\x1)} in  node[anchor={\n1-90}, inner sep=0,draw,circle] at ($(D)!0.15!90:(Q)$){$D$};

\draw[fill=green] ($(A)!0.15cm!-90:(S)$) circle (1pt);
\draw[dashed] ($(A)!0.15cm!-90:(S)$) -- ($(S)!0.15cm!90:(A)$);

\draw[fill=green] ($(B)!0.15cm!-90:(R)$) circle (1pt);
\draw[dashed] ($(B)!0.15cm!-90:(R)$) -- ($(R)!0.15cm!90:(B)$);

\draw[fill=green] ($(C)!0.15cm!90:(R)$) circle (1pt);
\draw[dashed] ($(C)!0.15cm!90:(R)$) -- ($(R)!0.15cm!-90:(C)$);

\draw[fill=green] ($(D)!0.15cm!90:(Q)$) circle (1pt);
\draw[dashed] ($(D)!0.15cm!90:(Q)$) -- ($(Q)!0.15cm!-90:(D)$);

\draw (P) -- (Q) -- (R) -- (S) -- cycle;
\node[anchor=east, inner sep=0] at ($(P) +(-0.15cm,0)$){$P$};
\node[anchor=south, inner sep=0] at ($(Q) +(0,0.15cm)$){$Q$};
\node[anchor=west, inner sep=0] at ($(R) +(0.15cm,0)$){$R$};
\node[anchor=north, inner sep=0] at ($(S) +(0,-0.15cm)$){$S$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: even green discs]